React Native reference to native object in TypeScript
Is it possible in a React Native (bridgeless) Turbo Native Module for a TypeScript function to return a reference to a native object? I don't want to use the reference directly, only to pass it as a parameter to another native function.
Something like:
RTNFoo/js/NativeFoo.ts:
export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  createFoo(): object;
}

The corresponding native function returns a Foo object.
I get a ParserError:
TypeScript type annotation 'TSObjectKeyword' is unsupported in NativeModule specs.

Wrapping the Foo in a Promise just defers the error to runtime.

don't use object as a type it's about and useful as any.  Type your objects, thats the point of typescript. If you really need a placeholder while you figure things out:  export interface IObject { [key: string]: any;}
